# Shell: run segment 1 or 2 of script dependent on $variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've been trying to figure out a way in Shell as to how I could run a different segment of a script dependent on the variable that was given. Here, the variables are either X or W.

```
while true; do
    read -p "Do you want to run X or W? (X/W) " xw
        case $xw in
            [Xx]* ) echo -e "Starting X prompt..." && server=$x;;
            [Ww]* ) echo -e "Starting W prompt..." && server=$w;;
            * ) echo -e "Incorrect input detected, repeating prompt...";;
        esac
    done
    
    (server=$x)
    while true; do
    read -p "What X do you want to enter? (Y/N) " yn
        case $yn in
            [Yy]* ) echo -e "Starting...\n" && exec test;;
            [Nn]* ) echo -e "Aborting...\n" && exit;;
            * ) echo -e "Incorrect input detected, repeating prompt...";;
        esac
    done

    (server=$w)
    while true; do
    read -p "What W do you want to enter? (Y/N) " yn
        case $yn in
            [Yy]* ) echo -e "Starting...\n" && exec test;;
            [Nn]* ) echo -e "Aborting...\n" && exit;;
            * ) echo -e "Incorrect input detected, repeating prompt...";;
        esac
    done
```

Is there a way I can create a "goto"-ish statement here that'd allow me to perform one of the two prompts depending on the variable? I haven't been able to figure it out yet. I appreciate any and all help.

Comment: Where do you set `$x` and `$w`?

Comment: `(server=$x)` doesn't do anything. It executes the assignment in a subshell, then the subshell exits immediately. I'm not sure why you're doing this, since you already assigned `server` in the `case` statement earlier.

Comment: @Barmar I am still learning to work with Shell and its properties. This was an example code more than anything, and I was confused as to how I could execute my idea here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all the code into the `case` statement.

```
while true; do
    read -p "Do you want to run X or W? (X/W) " xw
    case $xw in
        [Xx]* )
            echo -e "Starting X prompt..."
            server=$x
            while true; do
                read -p "What X do you want to enter? (Y/N) " yn
                case $yn in
                    [Yy]* ) echo -e "Starting...\n" && exec test;;
                    [Nn]* ) echo -e "Aborting...\n" && exit;;
                    * ) echo -e "Incorrect input detected, repeating prompt...";;
                esac
            done
            ;;              
        [Ww]* )
            echo -e "Starting W prompt..."
            server=$w
            while true; do
                read -p "What W do you want to enter? (Y/N) " yn
                case $yn in
                    [Yy]* ) echo -e "Starting...\n" && exec test;;
                    [Nn]* ) echo -e "Aborting...\n" && exit;;
                    * ) echo -e "Incorrect input detected, repeating prompt...";;
                esac
            done
            ;;
        * ) echo -e "Incorrect input detected, repeating prompt...";;
    esac
done
```

Comment: Perfect, works great! Thank you very much for the help, sir. Have a great weekend.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you would want to use functions for each case. Something like:

```
while read -p "Do you want to run X or W? (X/W) " xw; do
        case $xw in
        [Xx]*) run_x;;
        [Ww]*) run_w;;
        * ) echo -e "Incorrect input detected, repeating prompt..." >&2 ;;
        esac
done
```

In this case, there seems to be a *lot* of redundancy in the two code paths, so perhaps you just want something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read -p "Do you want to run X or W? (X/W) " xw; do
    case $xw in
    [Xx]* ) server=$x; prompt=X;;
    [Ww]* ) server=$w; prompt=W;;
    * ) unset prompt; printf '%s\n' "Invalid input" >&2;;
    esac
    if test -n "$prompt"; then
        printf '%s' "Starting $prompt prompt..."
        while read -p "What $prompt do you want to enter? (Y/N) " yn; do
            case $yn in
            [Yy]* ) printf "Starting...\n"; exec mytest;;
            [Nn]* ) printf "Aborting...\n"; exit;;
            * ) printf '%s\n' "Invalid input" >&2;;
            esac
        done
    fi
done
```

Don't call your executable `test`; there is already a common utility named `test` and using that name is bound to cause problems.  Write all error messages to stderr.   (It's not clear if `aborting...` is an error message; that's a judgement call.  If you decide to make it an error message, make sure you `exit 1`.)

Comment: Looks promising, however I do not think that it would be necessary to go this far with my script. Barmar already has given me a perfectly suitable answer. I'm still thankful for your response and help.

Comment: @Mephres code that produces the expected output is the starting point to a solution, not the end point. You have to also consider efficiency, portability, robustness, conciseness, etc. to come up with a good solution. As part of that - duplicate code is bad code. as it requires changes in multiple places as requirements evolve, is hard to debug, is easy to forget a leg when fixing a bug, etc. What William shows isn't going "this far", it's just a correct way to write the code.

Comment: @EdMorton The code I am currently using is the one from Barmar. It's not really duplicate and works as expected. Performance, reliability, stability, consistency and ease of access are all-inclusive with his method.

Comment: @Mephres it's about 33% duplicate code. All those other things are included either way. Try changing `echo -e "Aborting...\n"` to `echo -e "Quitting...\n"` in both answers and note that you have to change it in 1 place in Williams answer and 2 places in Barmars - that is the meaning of and the problem with duplicate code.